# Where is the Courtroom in The Guild 2 Renaissance?

Tags: guild-2

I've been called to the courtroom, arrived to the town-hall but seems to miss the meeting (there was no option related to the meeting).

Where is the Courtroom location?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

Go to the town-hall with the wanted character and enter the town-hall.

While in the building hover over the 'Exit building' icon, there you will see additional options like 'Assembly hall' and such.

Here is a link to a screen-shoot: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=749868030

This is so not intuitive!

Comment: found a video that shows that option, it's 5 sec before showing the leave building, HTH: https://youtu.be/Dp7_I1l4_Uw?t=4m28s